# get the path url of pop up and save it in a variable in current vue component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am using the window.open to open a pop up. Currently i am working with vue js, but cant find a way to save the url path of the new window opened in my component. i appreciated thansk.

```
 this.newWindow=window.open('https://example.com/123',
                "width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200")
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see more code, but try saving the url as data:

```
data() {
    return {
        popupUrl: 'https://example.com/123'
    }
}
```

You might also consider using a modal instead depending on the contents of your popup.

Comment: i meant save the url formthe open.window into my a variable in my component. I tried  `this.SSOLogin = window.open(''https://example.com/123',                 "width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200")      this.SSOLogin.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {          var splitOnce = event.url.split('.....) `